# Looking for a Trigger to change inserting strings?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, trigger

I have an MSSQL Server 2008 Database.
There are some tables in my Database like below :
table1, table2, table3, ....
each table has a NVARCHAR(50) field (`Name`)
Now, I wanna change the strings that each sql query inserts in this field
**e.g :**
We have a query that wanna insert "Sample Text" in `Name` field.
I wanna change it to "Sample Name" with a SQL Trigger

Is it Possible with sql triggers ? if so, How? I'm naive in T-SQL
Is there a better way to do it with SQL Server ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to use triggers thats your call, i am just suggesting a different approach

you can use the `Default Value or Binding` feature of a table

e.g in your `table1`, you can make the default value of `Name column = 'Sample Name'` by below script

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF_Table1_Name DEFAULT N'Sample Name' FOR Name
GO
```

Look at image below
[image: Table Default value of Column]

---

This code below adds a trigger to your table that works after insert, it updates the name added and replaces the `'x'` with `'*'`

```
CREATE TRIGGER ReplacingTrigger 
ON  table1  
AFTER INSERT 
AS  
BEGIN 
    UPDATE table1
    SET table1.name = replace(table1.name,'x','*')
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN inserted i on i.name = table1.name
END
```

i suggest if you have an ID in the table to use it in the joins to find the exact record inserted to make it accurate like below

```
CREATE TRIGGER ReplacingTrigger 
ON  table1  
AFTER INSERT 
AS  
BEGIN 
    UPDATE table1
    SET table1.name = replace(table1.name,'x','*')
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN inserted i on i.id= table1.id
END
```

Comment: `Sample Name` was just a sample, Actually I wanna change all `×` inserting chars to `*`

Comment: just to understand you better, you have a column called `name` that you want to update, by replacing specific characters every time an insertion happens

Comment: Yes, I wanna to change some specific chars whenever a string is inserted into the `Name` field

Comment: i updated the main post, i added code for trigger